# ArcGIS 10.5 Export File Format

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, export, arcgis-10.5

I am using ArcGIS 10.5 and I am unable to set the destination format when I try to export an image using the Export Raster option on ArcMap.

The steps:

[image]

But the destination format is locked on "File geodatabase".

[image]

On later versions I was able to choose the format in this field.

What can I do in order to activate this field and choose a different format (TIFF, JPEG, etc.)?

Comment: It's not locked. It's assumed. You've already selected a destination within a GDB so those options cannot be changed. Click save and the raster will export to the GDB you selected.  If you want a different format you need to select a folder (not a GDB) and optionally specify a file extension (.tiff, .jpg, etc.) otherwise it will default to ESRI grid.

Answer (score 12):

You are exporting to Default.gdb. You need to change the location to a folder and the format menu will be activated to choose among the list of formats.

[[image]

[[image]

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: @pmatos please read https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

You're attempting to store your output in a file geodatabase (the `Default.gdb` folder in the "Location" box). The only raster format you can store in an FGDB is a File Geodatabase Raster. If you want to save your raster as a JPG, TIFF, or something else, set the Location to a regular file folder rather than a .GDB folder.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the 'Location' to something else e.g. a folder. Then you can select the format of the raster you want to save.

Comment: the first time I tried to use this approach was not working. For some reason when I clicked on a folder name for destination, it was not working. Now it is working fine. Thank you